# Load data from Google Analytics in a Chart.js chart

Tags: php, laravel, google-analytics, chart.js, google-analytics-api

My question is: *How do I load data from Google Analytics in a Chart.js chart?*

I am writing a program with the Laravel framework (version 5.6) and use the Google Analytics API (not the Google Analytics Embed API)(version 3).

I get the data correctly presented in an array but I want to show it in a graph.

*Subquestion: Do I need to replace the data in datasets with a connection to the Google Analytics API?*

A simple chart from Chart.js:

```
<canvas id="userChart"></canvas>
<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById('userChart').getContext('2d');
    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {

    // The type of chart we want to create
    type: 'line',

    // The data for our dataset            
    data: {
        labels: ["dag 1", "dag 8", "dag 15", "dag 22", "dag 30"],
        datasets: [{
            label: "users",
            //backgroundColor: '#2f5ec4',
            borderColor: '#2f5ec4',
            data: [138, 163, 115, 124, 49],
        }]
    },
    // Configuration options go here
    options: {}
});
```

**Update:**
Example of how I get the Analytics data:

```
Route::get('/datatest', function()
{
    $analyticsData = 
    Analytics::fetchTotalVisitorsAndPageViews(Period::days(30));
    dd($analyticsData);
});
```

Example of the DD array:

[image: DD array]

Comment: how and where is this array of data obtained from ? You don't show us what you are asking kinda weird

Comment: @GaimZz Thanks for your comment! I updated my question with how I ask the data through a GET method in a route. This is how I test parts before I implement it further in the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be too late but for anyone who is in need, try the following. For your case you have your $analyticsData collection, which is a good start. Chartjs uses lists to map and compare data.
So for example we want to see a chart of date vs visitors

```
//transfer all of this code out of the routes to your controller

$analyticsData = Analytics::fetchTotalVisitorsAndPageViews(Period::days(30));

//send these two variables to your view

$dates = $analyticsData->pluck('date');
$visitors = $analyticsData->pluck('visitors');
```

In your script, the labels should receive $dates in a list as follows;

```
labels: {!! json_encode($dates) !!},
```

And data in datasets receive $visitors as a list;

```
data: {!! json_encode($visitors) !!}
```

[See this article](http://www.bryceandy.com/devblog/How-ChartJs-Can-Display-Laravel5-Analytics-Data) on my website for more in-depth explanations.